# Swift error with repeatActionForever: "missing argument for parameter 'completion'"?

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to have a sequence be executed forever, and the sequence works fine on its own; I just can't get it to run within `repeatActionForever`:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            block1.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            moveDownLeft,
            SKAction.runBlock({ self.block1.hidden = true}),
            moveUpLeft,
            SKAction.runBlock({ self.block1.hidden = false})])
            )))
```

I get this error on the first line: "missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call". What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`block1.runAction` does not return an `SKAction`.  It just performs the `SKAction`.If you are trying to create an SKAction that will run forever with the sequenced `SKAction` in your array, then remove the `block1.runAction` part

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
     moveDownLeft,
     SKAction.runBlock({
         self.block1.hidden = true
     }),
     SKAction.runBlock({
         self.block1.hidden = false
     }),
     moveUpLeft
     ])))
```